# How to use HTML tag?

Tags: discussion, support, tags

I am a little bit confused about how to use [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) tag. Here is the list of the [most upvoted questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html?sort=votes&pageSize=50) of [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html)

Here is a few questions of top ~20 most voted questions.

- [How to horizontally center a <div> in another <div>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-horizontally-center-a-div-in-another-div)
- [Is it possible to apply CSS to half of a character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23569441/is-it-possible-to-apply-css-to-half-of-a-character)
- [How to check whether a checkbox is checked in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/how-to-check-whether-a-checkbox-is-checked-in-jquery)
  (Maybe correct)
- [How can I know which radio button is selected via jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596351/how-can-i-know-which-radio-button-is-selected-via-jquery)
  (Maybe correct)
- [How to make div not larger than its contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450903/how-to-make-div-not-larger-than-its-contents)
- [How do I vertically center text with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-do-i-vertically-center-text-with-css)
- [Creating a div element in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867916/creating-a-div-element-in-jquery)
- [jQuery document.createElement equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268490/jquery-document-createelement-equivalent)

I thought [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) should not be in questions like above. Am I correct or should I add [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) when I am asking questions like those?

---

Update: I thought is because all above questions do nothing about HTML.

For example,

- 1,2,3 need only CSS....
- 3,4 also need only jQuery, but it might be good to tag as HTML.
- 5,6 : CSS
- 7, 8,9 : jQuery.

What I feel is, if those questions are tagged as HTML, many (not almost all, but near to it) CSS and JavaScript questions could also be tagged as HTML.

Comment: Why do you think those questions shouldn't have the [tag:html] tag?

Comment: @Stijn Because all above questions do nothing about HTML. For a example question 1,2,3 need ony CSS.... 3,4 also need only jQuery, but it might good tag as HTML. 5 JS,6 CSS, 7, CSS, 8,9 jQuery. What I feel is if those questions are tags as HTML, many(not almost all, but near to it) CSS, JavaScript questions also can be tagged as HTML.

Comment: I can't be bothered to go into detail for all examples, but let's take question 5. You say it's only about JS. The entire question is *"How can I change a class of an HTML element in response to an `onClick` event using JavaScript?"*, and you say it isn't about HTML? I disagree, it's about a combination of HTML and JS. The question wouldn't make any sense in a pure JS environment.

Comment: @Stijn Totally agree with question 5. It is my mistake and I removed it.

Comment: So you **don't** think [tag:html] should be used in a question titled: _"How to horizontally center a <div> in another <div>?"_?

Comment: I suggest you add to your question what you wrote in the first comment, an explanation per question why you disagree with the current tags. (I'm not saying you're right or wrong BTW, but you need to explain yourself a bit more.)

Comment: @Stijn I added it to the question

Comment: @AlonEitan Yes. Because if it is should be on HTML, many css questions (near to almost all) also should be in HTML tag.

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson About your etid, it's somewhat right (That's why I removed my DV from this question), it's certainly not the main tag, but usually any DOM manipulation/design is related to the actual HTML structure, so you can't have CSS without HTML element. And I often find myself VTC questions about DOM manipulation because they include only the JS part without the actual HTML structure (So those question  are very much HTML related, and that's why this tag is relevant)

Comment: My vote for exposing the reasoning and asking for feedback without any rant.

Comment: *And I often find myself VTC questions about DOM manipulation because they include only the JS part without the actual HTML structure* @AlonEitan I'm glad I'm not the only person irritated by that.

Comment: Its not A || B || C. there are pure javascript questions, but such questions have nothing to do with DOM manipulation or HTML whatsoever. I doubt there is a pure CSS question, but it might be possible. Most of the time, these tags are going to overlap (JS and CSS will have less overlap), and most of that overlap is appropriate. All of the links in your question should contain the HTML tag

Answer (score 6):

[html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) should be used in questions that are directly concerned with HTML -- reading, writing, parsing, manipulating etc.

Yes, that means that almost any [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) question will also be tagged [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), [dom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dom), [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) or [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery). The community doesn't currently see anything wrong with this AFAICS.

While a fraction of Javascript and CSS questions focus entirely on the respective code, most need some preexisting HTML to work off of.

A rule of thumb could be if you need a sample of HTML in the MCVE.

But in the end, this doesn't even matter much. At SO, tags serve two practical purposes: they help finding questions for those looking for an answer (they are given higher relevance weight as a keyword and for internal search, can be an explicit search term, too) and for those who give answers (allowing to watch them). Slapping [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) makes the question easier to find by this keyword and presents it to those watching the tag, that's all. So unless HTML is blatantly irrelevant to the question, there's no harm in adding the tag. And since all those technologies revolve around an HTML page, anything related to them is much more likely to involve HTML in some form and shape than not.

Comment: I'm actually not sure I agree. When presented with a question that features [tag:html] only because there is some html in the example to put into light a strange behaviour of javascript, the question is not actually about html, hence I would remove the tag (if I understand what you say?). From the edit rejections reasons: `"Tags should help to describe what the question is about, not just what it contains."`

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Greniernote Note the "MCVE" part. A correct MCVE cannot contain what is not required to reproduce the problem -- who knows, maybe the problem is really in the way the tags are written. The most important part to bear in mind is that there's a very large grey area here. So by all means, do not go on a rampage retagging people's questions because they "don't focus on HTML enough for your liking".

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier The community concensus, as per above, seems to be that in the close-knit family of client web technologies, it's not a big deal. So an OP has leeway about whether to include it, you can make an edit if you feel that the question will benefit, but retagging things on a large scale is not a constructive course of action.

Comment: I don't understand why you are speaking about retagging @ivan? Did I say I massively retag things? Why are you implying I would do that? Of course I know it's not the thing to do, what gives? I remove tags from questions when I review edits (if warranted), or when I organically happen upon one that needs it, but you implying it has no ground here. Please stop that.

Comment: Moreover, there's absolutely no "community consensus" above, there are comments with like 5 upvotes, that are not even close to actually say something definitive.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier You were pressing me to tell you which way of action is "correct". This suggests that you put in high regard "doing things right". So I used "don't go retagging" to emphasize that generally, either with or without the tag is "right" so you shouldn't label any questions as "doing things wrong" and actively go "fixing" them. "Community consensus"≈established practice.

Comment: Maybe there is a language issue here, but there was absolutely no pressing in my comments whatsoever. Actually, I did not ask anything of you, let alone tell me which way is correct, I voiced that I disagree with your answer by  quoting the site's edit rejection reasons. I trust you are familiar with them? Tags should not simply express everything that is in a question. *That* is estalished practice. My self-deleted comment said why: even if there's html in a mcve, it does not necessarily mean that the *answer*, or even *problem*, is about html.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Alright, I apologize if I inadvertently offended you. (In my culture, forcing one's views on others is a big problem, maybe I'm just seeing it everywhere :-) ) Anyway, I think I've said everything I can say on the question's matter.

Comment: :) yeah I can also react strongly to things. I really did not like being associated with massive retagging, sorry about that. I realize that might have been petty of me.